# How to access a View stacked on top of another View with UIApplication?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to convert views to images by accessing the `UIApplication.shared.windows` context.

I'm able to grab the content view with `UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.view` and convert it to an image. Later, a user can draw on top of my view and I want to be able to grab the view stacked upon the original view.

I thought that accessing the subviews would give me that `UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.subviews` but I end up with blank images so I believe my intuition is incorrect.

How would I access those stacked views?

```
ZStack {
   VStack { //some view }
   VStack { //some other view that only appears when user draws }
}
```

[image]

I'd like to grab just the pink view (user drawn) but I'm only able to grab the entire content view.

Comment: The digging would be quite extensive you can try an look at how [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) works. It is likely under many layers of view controllers and views. But you might be able to access it with introspect.

Comment: SwiftUI views cannot (and actually should not) be accessed in that way. In a fact SwiftUI view is only a data description of what should be rendered into one context. In SwiftUI you manipulate with data not with views. If you still need that use UIKit classes for your UI.

Comment: @Asperi is there by chance a way to directly convert a `Shape` into a `UIView`? Like a method `.convertShapeToUiView`, this would allow me to avoid attempting to access it in this ways. I'm trying to compare two `Shape` by converting them to bitmaps

Comment: `UIHostingController(rootView: YourSwiftUIShape()).view`

Comment: Amazing! I'll try this out tomorrow and loop back, thanks so much

Comment: @Asperi so the `Shape` does get converted but when accessing `.view` and converting it to an image I get a blank image, any tips on debugging here?